# svmono + newfloat - caption: how to adjust spacing separating the caption and the float contents

Tags: spacing, captions, sv-classes, newfloat

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{svmono}% Version 5.5, available from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=htb,name={Spec.}]{specification}
%\usepackage[labelsep=space,justification=RaggedRight,labelfont={small,bf},textfont={small},skip=0pt]{caption}%%% Possible in an MWE, but leads to a different style than prescribed by Springer. It is difficult to reduce the vertical gap ONLY; including this package introduces a whole bunch of other changes.
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\belowcaptionskip=0pt
\skip41=0pt
\skip42=0pt
\figcapgap=0pt%%% only for svmono, won't work with article
\tabcapgap=0pt%%% doesn't help either, as noticed by Axel
\begin{document}
\begin{specification}
  \noindent\strut\hrulefill\\[-.4\baselineskip]
  Line 1\\
  \(\vdots\)\\
  Line 9\\[-.8\baselineskip]%
  \strut\hrulefill%
  \caption{Too much space between the line just above and this caption.}%
  \end{specification}
\end{document}
```

The result is roughly as follows (I can't upload the image for an unknown reason; SE says imgur rejects the request):

```
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
Line 1
⁝
Line 9
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

Spec. 1  Too much space between the line just above and this caption.
```

How to reduce the gap between the second horizontal rule and the caption? My standard solution is to insert something like `\\[-.3\baselineskip]%` as a new line right before `\caption{...}`, but the actual gap (`-.3\baselineskip` above) is a wild guess and thus fragile, as well as the other hardcoded skips you see in the code.  In general, I would like to reduce the hardcoding of the adjustments one by one.  In this question, I would like to get rid of only one vertical gap, namely the one before the caption, in an automatic way.  I know how to do it in the `article` class, and I know how to do it with the package `caption`, which, however, changes the defaults a lot (which is NOT wanted in this question).  As the reader might see in the source code, I tried to set some lengths known to me to 0pt, but nothing helped.

Comment: Behavior of svmono: If the floating environment is `figure`, `\figcapgap` will be applied above the caption. Otherwise `\tabcapgap` will be applied below the caption. So in your case no skip will be applied above the caption (because it's no `figure` environment), and therefore there is no skip you can adjust to decrease the space between content and caption. (To change that one needs to re-define `\@makecaption` offered by the `svmono` document class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the definition of \capstrut. By default it inserts a strut of 10pt height:

```
\documentclass{svmono}%
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=htb,name={Spec.}]{specification}

\begin{document}
\begin{specification}
  \noindent\strut\hrulefill\\[-.4\baselineskip]
  Line 1\\
  \(\vdots\)\\
  Line 9\\[-.8\baselineskip]%
  \strut\hrulefill
  \caption{Too much space between the line just above and this caption.}%
\end{specification}

\renewcommand\capstrut{\strut}
\begin{specification}
  \noindent\strut\hrulefill\\[-.4\baselineskip]
  Line 1\\
  \(\vdots\)\\
  Line 9\\[-.8\baselineskip]%
  \strut\hrulefill
  \caption{Too much space between the line just above and this caption.}%
\end{specification}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{specification}{\renewcommand\capstrut{\strut}}`